# Pandas groupby selecting only two values based on 2 groups and converting rest to 0

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

This is following on from my question here which was answered: [Pandas groupby selecting only one value based on 2 groups and converting rest to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48126766/pandas-groupby-selecting-only-one-value-based-on-2-groups-and-converting-rest-to)

I have a pandas data frame which has a datetime index which looks like this:

df =

```
           Fruit    Quantity
01/02/10    Apple   4
01/02/10    Apple   6
01/02/10    Apple   12
01/02/10    Pear    7
01/02/10    Grape   8
01/02/10    Grape   5
02/02/10    Apple   2
02/02/10    Fruit   6
02/02/10    Pear    8
02/02/10    Pear    5
02/02/10    Apple   2
02/02/10    Apple   2
```

Now for each date and for each fruit I only want two values (preferably the top two) and the rest of the fruit for the date to remain zero. So desired output is as follows:

```
           Fruit    Quantity
01/02/10    Apple   4
01/02/10    Apple   6
01/02/10    Apple   0
01/02/10    Pear    7
01/02/10    Grape   8
01/02/10    Grape   5
02/02/10    Apple   2
02/02/10    Fruit   6
02/02/10    Pear    8
02/02/10    Pear    5
02/02/10    Apple   2
02/02/10    Apple   0
```

This is only a small example, but my main data frame has over 3 million rows and the fruit are not necessarily in order per date.

Thanks

Comment: it would be helpful to see what you tried and why the result was unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `cumcount` grouped by `date(index)` and `Fruit`, then zero out rows where the count is larger than `1`:

```
df['QuanityTrimmed'] = df.Quantity.where(df.groupby([df.index, df.Fruit]).cumcount() < 2, 0)

print(df)
#          Fruit  Quantity  QuanityTrimmed
#01/02/10  Apple         4               4
#01/02/10  Apple         6               6
#01/02/10  Apple        12               0
#01/02/10   Pear         7               7
#01/02/10  Grape         8               8
#01/02/10  Grape         5               5
#02/02/10  Apple         2               2
#02/02/10  Fruit         6               6
#02/02/10   Pear         8               8
#02/02/10   Pear         5               5
#02/02/10  Apple         2               2
#02/02/10  Apple         2               0
```

Comment: Nice and succinct !